# How to customize WordPress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, dashboard

I bought a WordPress template and it adds some new "categories" in the WordPress Dashboard.
(Such as "Works", "Trends", "Fashions", "Styles" in the screenshot)
However, I would like to do some modification to them, is that possible?
Is there a way to manage this "categories"? 
Or which keyword I could use to search for more information?

Best Regards

[image: WordPress Dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are Custom Post Types - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types for more info.
They're defined in your theme's functions.php file, where you can edit their properties.

Check out this plugin if you want a visual interface raher than messing with code: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/